# SignalR, Owin do not work after VS2015 move and package updates

Tags: signalr, owin, signalr-hub

I recently upgraded to VS2015 (did not remove VS2013 or 2010). NuGet did not instal properly. While the project ran it loaded with streaming messages re package updating. I just removed and reinstalled NuGet and updated all packages. 
Now I have 2 problems that could be related. 
1) 134 errors. Everything to do with SignalR and Owin is failing with messages like:
'type or namespace 'Hub' could not be found'.

Here is the key code. Other Usings were greyed out as unnecessary, and are removed.

```
using System;

namespace SignalR
{
[Microsoft.SignalR.HubName("SeekerHub")]
  public class SeekerHub : Hub
  {
        private static Decimal number;

        public static void SendMessage(string message)
        {
              //StartTimer();
              //var callingClient = Context.ConnectionId;
              var hubContext =      GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SeekerHub>();

              if (Decimal.TryParse(message, out number))
              {
                    if (number == 0)
                    { }
                    hubContext.Clients.All.receiveUpdate(message);
              }
              else
                    hubContext.Clients.All.receiveNotification(message);
        }
    }
}
```

2) 6 warnings that relate to updating. All relate to the same SignalR/Owin area but the message suggests that it is looking in the VS2013/localhost xyz/ file and not in the VS2015 file. Is there a way I can change the pointer when the package looks to update itself?

Thanks, in advance, for any help.

Comment: You need "using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;" at the top of the file for the specific error you mention.

Comment: Steve, it simply underlines the SignalR part in red and greys the whole line out when I add it, with the comment "using directive is not necessary. The type or namespace SignalR does not exist in the namespace Microsoft.AspNet (are you missing an assembly reference)

Comment: Steve sorry I hit enter. It suggests possible fixes one of which is using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR; which appears, then a resline appears under SignalR, then it is all greyed out, and then the redline disappears. Now I have clean code in that the references inside the method seem OK and I just have the greyed out line that you suggested.

Comment: Steve, part 3. At that point look OK (?). Run it and bacl to square 1 with 88 errrors!